# Help identifying a failed SOT23 component via markings “Nos”

Tags: identification, sot23

[image: Failed component]

This part may be damaged (outwardly it’s intact). It comes from a proprietary video card from 18+ years ago I’m trying to fix (finding another card has been a challenge).

This component currently only has a diode connection between one of the leg pair and the third leg. I think the other combinations are open circuit.

The part appears to sit between two different voltage rails (on the leg pair).  I assume it uses a lower voltage (5 V) to signal a 12 V part or enable line.

The marking seems fairly clear but unless I’m reading to backwards or something I cannot find any SMD book, online search, or catalog with this marking.

To me it starts with “N” and appears to have a small case “o” & “s”.  With a data code going sideways.

I’ve seen biased transistors on something like N05 with this marking layout. But outside the layout the actual letters don’t correspond to any data sheet I can find.

I’m hoping this component gets me closer to fixing my item.

Comment: "The part appears to sit between two different voltage rails (on the leg pair). I assume it uses a lower voltage (5 V) to signal a 12 V part or enable line." - is it connected directly to the rails? Or to signals that are derived from those rails? Or through a resistor? etc?

Comment: This part has been suggested to be a Vishay TN0200T N-channel MOSFET. However the markings still aren’t quite right to me.  I’m going to try to test that assumption. 

I tracked this component using only ohms down the 5v and 12v rails.  While the specs claim it’s suppose to be pulsed in operation, I didn’t see an obvious pulse-sending mechanism (hence unsure if it’s a mosfet).  

This area has lots of 1K and some 2K resistor arrays, so yes, a lot of the current is limited through very small resistor arrays for these components.

Comment: A measurable diode connection and possible base resistors around could suggest a BJT (potentially with a damaged collector if this part only reads one diode drop and open ckt on the third pin), but I am not certain by any means.

Comment: We’ll whatever it is, it’s  likely some form of mosfet as I can switch it in and off, I don’t think it’s biased as I don’t see kilohms of resistance anywhere.  Since it works I’m placing it back, darn, I thought I was into something.